# Java unable to print all lines from file1.txt to file2.txt?

Tags: java

I am reading lines from file1.txt, and copying only a select few lines to file2.txt. But java doesn't copy all the lines that should be copied according to my code. The bottom 625 lines are not copied. I must note that the lines that should be copied all show up on the console. So there is no problem with the txt file. What is going wrong here? The code is below:

```
InputStream i = new FileInputStream("file1.txt");
        InputStreamReader is=new InputStreamReader(i);
        BufferedReader bsa = new BufferedReader(iq);

        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("file2.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pr=new PrintWriter(bw);

        String z="";
        for(int i=0;i<3137;i++){
            z=bsa.readLine();
            for(int q=0;q<2538;q++){
                if(array1[i].equals(array2[q])==true){
                    System.out.println(z);//to see printed lines in console
                    pr.println(z);//printing to file2
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where did you get you magic numbers from?

Comment: hardcode lol. I had to close printwriter, as the people said below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you close the `PrintWriter` ?

```
pr.close();
```

`PrintWriter` buffers data until its its buffer is full upon which it writes to disk. It has a default buffer size of [8192 characters](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#BufferedWriter.0defaultCharBufferSize) making it easily possible for several hundred lines to remain unwritten until `close` is called.

Comment: Beat me by a bit, you win this round :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your `PrintWriter` using `pr.close();`

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy from one file to another I would recommend this:

```
    try (final InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file1);
            final OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file2)) {
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int numRead = -1;
        while ((numRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
    }
```

It uses java 7 try-with-resources syntax; it also avoids you magic numbers.

You can also use `FileChannel`, this is a little simpler:

```
    try (final FileChannel source = new RandomAccessFile(file1, "r").getChannel();
            final FileChannel dest = new RandomAccessFile(file2, "rw").getChannel()) {
        source.transferTo(0, source.size(), dest);
    }
```

Comment: Java NIO with a `FileChannel` is far superior to the antiquated method of reading bytes into memory and writing out to file. Using `FileChannel` can actually let the OS be smart about copying the file. Also, the OP doesn't want to copy everything.

Comment: @TimBender I was just extending the OP's original method; I have added an NIO example too.

Comment: Yes. Removed the down vote (since it is not objectionable), but the OP still only wants a select set of lines.